# console.log formats error object different from Error.prototype.toString

Tags: javascript, tostring

I am seeing the Error.prototype.toString implementation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/toString).

It mostly prints `error.name` and `error.message` as `name + ': ' + msg`.

But when i pass `Error` object to `console.log`, I am seeing the `file not exists` error prints more properties as `errno, code, syscall` etc.

What does `console.log` invoke, to print the string summary of an Error object?

Code:

```
var fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('/abcd', 'utf8', function(err, res){
  console.log("the error toString method shows, " + err)
  console.log("the console log's string summary is,")
  console.log(err)
})
```

Output:

```
the error toString method shows, Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/abcd'
the console log's string summary is,
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/abcd'] errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'open', path: '/abcd' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

console.log is unspecified, so each browser implements something different. (As does Node.js.) If you want to see exactly what, you can look at the browser source code, except for IE/Edge of course.

In Node.js, which I assume you are using because of the `require`, the code is:

- [console.log calls util.format](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/cc2ceb6cb96b1b448de234a9e7abb32acc2fbbad/lib/console.js#L36)
- [util.format calls an internal `inspect` function](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/cc2ceb6cb96b1b448de234a9e7abb32acc2fbbad/lib/util.js#L17)
- [which calls an internal `formatValue` function](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/cc2ceb6cb96b1b448de234a9e7abb32acc2fbbad/lib/util.js#L109)
- [which in this case calls an internal `formatError` function](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/cc2ceb6cb96b1b448de234a9e7abb32acc2fbbad/lib/util.js#L398)

  - [which invokes `Error.prototype.toString` surrounded by braces](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/cc2ceb6cb96b1b448de234a9e7abb32acc2fbbad/lib/util.js#L490)
  - [but also calls a `formatter` passing along the visible keys, thus giving the extra bits](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/cc2ceb6cb96b1b448de234a9e7abb32acc2fbbad/lib/util.js#L437)